# Unmarshal list when list and elements have same names

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I got a tricky XML to unmarshal:

```
<suppliers>
<suppliers id="1"/> 
...
<suppliers_options>
<suppliers_options supplr_id="1" option_type_id="1"/>
...
</suppliers_options>
<suppliers_ratios>
<spr site_id="1" supplr_id="1" ratio="0"/>
...
</suppliers_ratios>
</suppliers>
```

My first intention was to do something like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "suppliers")
public class SupplierDto {
    @XmlElement(name = "suppliers")
    private Supplier suppliers;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "suppliers_options")
    @XmlElement(name = "suppliers_options")
    private List<SuppliersDistrib> suppliersOptions;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "suppliers_ratios")
    @XmlElement(name = "sr")
    private List<SuppliersRatio> suppliersRatios;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "suppliers")
public class Supplier {
...
}
```

But because the root element and list element both named "suppliers" it gives me an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class _.Supplier cannot be cast to _.SupplierDto (_.Supplier and _.SupplierDto are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

When I remove *@XmlRootElement(name = "suppliers")* on supplier class it starting to unmarshal correctly.

Can somebody explain what is the right way to approach this tricky XML and why does my workaround works?

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is not valid.

Right approach here is to create `xsd schema` first and then you will be able to unmarshall/generate java classes using `xjc` java utility.